# How to find an array in string format in pandas using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which contains only one column that looks like this
df1

```
Col_A
Name
Address
[B00-OUI_001]
Soemthing else
etc.
```

and another that has something like this.

df2

```
Col_B
[B00-OUI_000_V]
[B00-OUI_002_V]
[B00-OUI_003_V] 
[B00-OUI_001_V]
[B00-OUI_005_V]
[B00-OUI_006_V]
[B00-OUI_007_V]
```

I am trying to find out matching entries from df2 in df1 like `B00-OUI_001` is in both df but in df2 its with `_V`, so it turned to regular expression as everything is in string format, but have been failing in exact match. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: what is expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove trailing `[]` in both columns and filter with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with tuples:

```
tups = tuple(df1['Col_A'].str.strip('[]').unique())

df2 = df2[df2['Col_B'].str.strip('[]').str.startswith(tups)]
print (df2)
            Col_B
3  [B00OUI_001_V]
```

Another idea is join unique values by `|` for regex `OR` and use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
v = '|'.join(df1['Col_A'].str.strip('[]').unique())

df2 = df2[df2['Col_B'].str.strip('[]').str.contains(v)]
print (df2)
            Col_B
3  [B00OUI_001_V]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's only "_V" that can disrupt exact match, why not get rid of it and create a dummy column index? Exact join always will be faster than any kid of regex-mapping.

What I mean:

```py
df2["Col_B_edt"]=df2["Col_B"].str.replace("_V]", "]")

df3=pd.merge(df,df2,left_on="Col_A",right_on="Col_B_edt").drop("Col_B_edt", axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
   Col_A          Col_B
0  [B00-OUI_001]  [B00-OUI_001_V]
```